# netsuite SDF error when deploy on WebStorm

Tags: webstorm, netsuite, sdf

**SDF Features are enabled.**

On webstorm, I can validate (netsuite ide function) and it works.

When I try to the project, even if it's empty or not, the LOG returns:

The remote server returned an error:
            https://system.na2.netsuite.com:443/app/suiteapp/devframework/ideinstallhandler.nl - Moved Temporarily

Answer (score 4):

I solved this error by Adding the SuiteApp Deployment permission to the SDF Role attached to my account.
Please follow the guide on how to create the SDF Role in this document.

https://docs.oracle.com/cloud/latest/netsuitecs_gs/NSCDF/NSCDF.pdf  -  PAGE 7

Answer (score 1):

I got this error with Eclipse after our account was upgraded to 2018.2 and I stopped logging in as Administrator.

This seems to be a permissions problem; I fixed it by [creating an SDF Developer role](https://netsuite.custhelp.com/app/answers/detail/a_id/51761) with the permissions listed in that SuiteAnswers article, and then logging into the role using a token, following the links in the note on step 5. (You may not need to use the token; I didn't try it the other way.)